# SEO friendly url on php

Tags: php, seo

i need to convert this type of url

yourdomain.com/username/listings/id1/

to this

yourdomain.com/username/listings/listing-name

Can i get some advice? Thank you!

Comment: you need url rewriting in .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at htaccess, then change the links you want to make SEO on.

Comment: its not enough. i know that i need to convert listing title from lets say "listing name" to "listing-name"

Comment: Why it's not enough? When you enable url rewriting in htaccess, then you have to generate the corresponding links.